# How do I count the number of elements in a list?

Tags: list, prolog

I need to write a small Prolog program to count the number of occurrence of each element in a list.

```
numberOfRepetition(input, result)
```

For example:

```
numberOfRepetition([a,b,a,d,c,a,b], X)
```

can be satisfied with `X=[a/3,b/2,d/1,c/1]` because `a` occurs three times, `b` occurs 2 times and `c` and `d` one time.

Comment: We don't just give answers.  Take your best shot at it, post your code along with any error messages, and we'll help improve it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to give you the answer, so I gonna help you with it:

```
% Find the occurrences of given element in list
%
% occurrences([a,b,c,a],a,X).
% -> X = 2.

occurrences([],_,0).
occurrences([X|Y],X,N):- occurrences(Y,X,W),N is W + 1.
occurrences([X|Y],Z,N):- occurrences(Y,Z,N),X\=Z.
```

Depending on your effort and feedback, I can help you to get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027124/4609915) to the related question "[How to count number of element occurrences in a list in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776759/how-to-count-number-of-element-occurrences-in-a-list-in-prolog)"!
In that  answer I present the predicate `list_counts/2`, which should fot your needs.

Sample use:

```
:- list_counts([a,b,a,d,c,a,b],Ys).
Ys = [a-3, b-2, d-1, c-1].
```

Note that that this predicate uses a slightly different representation for key-value pairs expressing multiplicity: principal functor `(-)/2` instead of `(/)/2`.

If possible, switch to the representation using `(-)/2` for better interoperability with standard library predicates (like `keysort/2`).

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to find element with max occurrences:

```
occurrences([],_,0).
occurrences([X|Y],X,N):- occurrences(Y,X,W),N is W + 1.
occurrences([X|Y],Z,N):- occurrences(Y,Z,N),X\=Z.

**make_list(Max):-
   findall((Num,Elem),occurrences([d,d,d,a,a,b,c,d,e],Elem,Num),L),
   sort(L,Sorted),
   last(Sorted,(_,Max)).**
```