# How to count number of element occurrences in a list in Prolog

Tags: list, count, prolog

i m new in prolog that s why may be the question is easy for you but i couldnt find the answer. Can someone please help me.

I just want

a count function s.t

```
count([c,c,a,a,b,b,d,a,c,b,d,d,a], O).
```

it will returns the number of occurences of the list members.

```
 O = [[a, 4], [b, 3], [c, 3], [d, 3]]
```

Comment: Did you try something and it did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is based on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432897/4609915) to "[Remove duplicates in list (Prolog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260792/remove-duplicates-in-list-prolog)" and on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) to the question "[Prolog union for A U B U C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c)".

`list_item_subtracted_count0_count/5` is derived from `list_item_subtracted/3`.
`list_counts/2` is derived from `list_setB/2`, which were both [defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432897/4609915).

```
list_item_subtracted_count0_count([], _, [], N,N).
list_item_subtracted_count0_count([A|As], E, Bs1, N0,N) :-
   if_(A = E,
       ( Bs1 =    Bs , N1 is N0+1 ), 
       ( Bs1 = [A|Bs], N1 =  N0   )),
   list_item_subtracted_count0_count(As, E, Bs, N1,N).

list_counts([], []).
list_counts([X|Xs], [X-N|Ys]) :-
   list_item_subtracted_count0_count(Xs, X, Xs0, 1,N),
   list_counts(Xs0, Ys).
```

Here's the query the OP gave:

```
?- list_counts([c,c,a,a,b,b,d,a,c,b,d,d,a], Xss).
Xss = [c-3,a-4,b-3,d-3].                    % succeeds deterministically
```

Note the order of pairs `X-N` in `Counts` corresponds to the first occurrence of `X` in `Xs`:

```
?- list_counts([a,b,c,d], Xss).
Xss = [a-1,b-1,c-1,d-1].

?- list_counts([d,c,b,a], Xss).
Xss = [d-1,c-1,b-1,a-1].
```

Last, let's consider all possible lists `Es`—enumerated fairly with ascending lengths:

```
?- length(Es, N), list_counts(Es, Xss).
   N = 0, Es = [],      Xss = []
;  N = 1, Es = [A],     Xss = [A-1]
;  N = 2, Es = [A,A],   Xss = [A-2]
;  N = 2, Es = [A,B],   Xss = [A-1,B-1],     dif(B,A)
;  N = 3, Es = [A,A,A], Xss = [A-3]
;  N = 3, Es = [A,A,B], Xss = [A-2,B-1],     dif(B,A)
;  N = 3, Es = [A,B,A], Xss = [A-2,B-1],     dif(B,A)
;  N = 3, Es = [B,A,A], Xss = [B-1,A-2],     dif(A,B), dif(A,B)
;  N = 3, Es = [A,B,C], Xss = [A-1,B-1,C-1], dif(C,A), dif(C,B), dif(B,A)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
co(X,L) :- co(X,[],L).

co([],A,A).
co([X|Xs], A, L) :- p(X-Z,A,R), !, Z1 is Z+1, co(Xs, [X-Z1|R], L). 
co([X|Xs], A, L) :- co(Xs, [X-1|A], L). 

p(X-Y,[X-Y|R],R):- !.
p(X,[H|Y], [H|Z]) :- p(X,Y,Z).
```

I did not use very meaningful names on purpose. Try to understand what each one of the predicates does.