# Collecting Items and Counting the Number of Occurrences

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I am trying to write a recursive rule `collCount/2` which groups identical items in a list with their respective numbers of occurrences into tuples.

For example, `collCount([a,b,a,b,c,b],F)` binds `F` with `[(a,2),(b,3),(c,1)]`. When running this query, Prolog simply returns `no`.

The following is what I have managed to do so far:

```
collCount([H|T],[(H,N)|L2]) :-
    countDel(H,[H|T],L,N),
    collCount(L,L2).

countDel(X,T,Rest,N) :-
    occur(X,T,N),
    delAll(X,T,Rest).

occur(_,[],0).
occur(X,[X|T],N) :-
    occur(X,T,NN),
    N is NN + 1.
occur(X,[H|T],N) :-
    occur(X,T,N),
    X \= H.

delAll(_,[],[]).
delAll(X,[X|T],Ans) :-
    delAll(X,T,Ans).
delAll(X,[H|T],[H|Rest]) :-
    delAll(X,T,Rest),
    X \= H.
```

The predicate `countDel/4` counts and deletes all occurrences of a specific item in a list. For instance, `countDel(2,[1,2,3,2,2],L,N)` binds L with `[1,3]` and `N` with `3`.

The predicate `occur/3` counts all occurrences of a specific item in a list. For instance, `occur(3,[1,2,3,4,3],Num)` binds `Num` with `2`.

The predicate `delAll/3` deletes all occurrences of a specific item in a list. For instance, `delAll(3,[1,2,3,4,3],L)` binds `L` with `[1,2,4]`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered sorting the list first, using `msort/2`? It will make the job easier. Outside of that, if you could fill in a brief description (one sentence or two) for each predicate you've defined, explaining their meaning, it could help clarify the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have. However, I am trying to avoid using built-in predicates. I wrote a recursive rule which sorts lists, but it only sorts lists containing numbers. Also, I have added the descriptions for the predicates above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is mostly correct. I've placed comments where I modified it.

```
collCount([],[]).  % miss base case
collCount([H|T],[(H,N)|L2]) :-
    countDel(H,[H|T],L,N),
    collCount(L,L2).

countDel(X,T,Rest,N) :-
    occur(X,T,N),
    delAll(X,T,Rest).

occur(_,[],0).
occur(X,[X|T],N) :-
    occur(X,T,NN),
    N is NN + 1.
occur(X,[H|T],N) :-
    occur(X,T,N),
    X \= H.

delAll(_,[],[]).
delAll(X,[X|T],Ans) :-
    delAll(X,T,Ans).
delAll(X,[H|T],[H|Rest]) :-
    X \= H,  % moved before recursive call
    delAll(X,T,Rest).
```

this yields

```
?- collCount([a,b,a,b,c,b],F).
F = [ (a, 2), (b, 3), (c, 1)] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I ask you why you moved that goal before the recursive call?

Comment: I've done it 'automatically', for efficiency. It's useless to recurse the full list and then discard the result... But the program should work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to draw your attention to a little part of your and @CapelliC's solution. Innocuous as:

```
occur(_,[],0) :- false.
occur(X,[X|T],N) :-
    occur(X,T,NN), false,
    N is NN + 1.
occur(X,[H|T],N) :-
    occur(X,T,N), false,
    X \= H.
```

So what I did here was to insert some goals **`false`** into your program. In this manner this program will now take less inferences than without. Still, there is something remarkable. Consider:

```
?- length(As,M), M>9, maplist(=(a),As), \+ time(occur(a,As,_)).
% 3,072 inferences, 0.002 CPU in 0.002 seconds (100% CPU, 1989931 Lips)
As = [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a|...],
M = 10 ;
% 6,144 inferences, 0.003 CPU in 0.003 seconds (100% CPU, 2050613 Lips)
As = [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a|...],
M = 11 ;
% 12,288 inferences, 0.006 CPU in 0.006 seconds (100% CPU, 2128433 Lips)
As = [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a|...],
M = 12
```

Have you seen enough? The number of inferences doubles when adding one further element. Brief, there is **exponential overhead**! You need to put the goal for inequality first. Even better, use `dif(X, H)`.

Note that this property is independent of being tail-recursive or not. There is still some place for optimizations, but far less than by this one.

See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more examples to use this technique.

Answer (score 3):

For a logically pure implementation look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027124/4609915) to the related question
"[How to count number of element occurrences in a list in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776759/how-to-count-number-of-element-occurence-in-a-list-in-prolog)".

In that answer I present an implementation of `list_counts/2` which preserves [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).

Let's put `list_counts/2` to use!

```
?- list_counts([a,b,a,b,c,b],F).
F = [a-2, b-3, c-1].
```

Note that `list_counts/2` represents pairs of `K` and `V` as `K-V`. In general, this is preferable to representations based on comma `(K,V)` or lists `[K,V]` for a number of reasons (readability, interoperability with other standard library predicates, efficiency).

If you *really need* to use the comma-based notation, you can define `collCount/2` as follows:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

collCount(Xs,Fss) :-
    list_counts(Xs,Css),
    maplist(\ (K-V)^(K,V)^true,Css,Fss).
```

So let's put `collCount/2` to use:

```
?- collCount([a,b,a,b,c,b],F).
F = [(a,2), (b,3), (c,1)].           % succeeds deterministically
```

---

#### Edit 2015-05-13

Out of curiosity, let's consider the performance aspect that @false referred to in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471600/4609915).

The following query roughly corresponds to the one that @false used in his answer. In both, we are interested in the effort required for 
universal termination:

```
?- length(As,M), 
   M>9, 
   maplist(=(a),As), 
   time((list_item_subtracted_count0_count(As,a,_,1,_),false ; true)).
% 73 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (95% CPU, 1528316 Lips)
As = [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a|...],
M = 10 ;
% 80 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (96% CPU, 1261133 Lips)
As = [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a|...],
M = 11 ;
% 87 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (96% CPU, 1315034 Lips)
As = [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a|...],
M = 12 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
frequencies_of( []     , []     ) .  % empty list? success!
frequencies_of( [X|Xs] , [F|Fs] ) :- % non-empty list?
  count( Xs , X:1 , F , X1 ) ,       % count the occurrences of the head, returning the source list with all X removed
  frequencies_of( X1 , Fs )          % continue
  .                                  %

count( [] , F , F , [] ) .           % empty list? success: we've got a final count.
count( [H|T] , X:N , F , Fs ) :-     % otherwise...
  H = X ,                            % - if the head is what we're counting, 
  N1 is N+1 ,                        % - increment the count
  count( T , X:N1 , F , Fs )         % - recurse down
  .                                  %
count( [H|T] , X:N , F , [H|Fs] ) :- % otherwise...
  H \= X ,                           % - if the head is NOT what we're counting
  count( T , X:N , F , Fs )          % - recurse down, placing the head in the remainder list
  .                                  %
```

Another way of looking at it:

```
frequencies_of( Xs , Fs ) :-     % compile a frequency table
  frequencies_of( Xs , [] , Fs ) % by invoking a worker predicate with its accumulator seeded with the empty list
  .

frequencies_of( []     , Fs , Fs ) .  % the worker predicate ends when the source list is exhausted
frequencies_of( [X|Xs] , Ts , Fs ) :- % otherwise...
  count( X , Ts , T1 ) ,              % - count X in the accumulator
  frequencies_of( Xs , T1 , Fs )      % - and recursively continue
  .                                   %

count( X , []       , [X:1]     ) .   % if we get to the end, we have a new X: count it
count( X , [X:N|Ts] , [X:N1|Ts] ) :-  % otherwise, if we found X,
  N1 is N+1                           % - increment the count
  .                                   % - and end.
count( X , [T:N|Ts] , [T:N|Fs]  ) :-  % otherwise
  X \= T ,                            % - assuming we didn't find X
  increment( X , Ts , Fs )            % - just continue looking
  .                                   % Easy!
```

A third approach would be to sort the list first, without removing duplicates. Once the list is ordered, a simple 1-pass, run-length encoding of the ordered list gives you the frequency table, something like this:

```
frequencies_of( Xs , Fs ) :- % to compute the frequencies of list elements
  msort( Xs , Ts ) ,         % - sort the list (without removing duplicates)
  rle( Ts , Fs )             % - then run-length encode the sorted list
  .                          % Easy!

rle( []    , [] ) .    % the run length encoding of an empty list is the empty list.
rle( [H|T] , Rs ) :-   % the run length encoding is of a non-empty list is found by
  rle( T , H:1 , Rs )  % invoking the worker on the tail with the accumulator seeded with the head
  .                    %

rle( []    , X:N , [X:N] ) .     % the end of the source list ends the current run (and the encoding).
rle( [H|T] , X:N , Rs    ) :-    % otherwise...
  H = X     ,                    % - if we have a continuation of the run,
  N1 is N+1 ,                    % - increment the count
  rle( T , X:N1 , Rs )           % - and recursively continue
  .                              %
rle( [H|T] , X:N , [X:N|Rs] ) :- % otherwise...
  H \= X ,                       % - if the run is at an end,
  rle( T , H:1 , Rs)             % - recursively continue, starting a new run and placing the current encoding in the result list.
  .                              %
```